# How to display logged in user information in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, webapi

I am new to Xamarin and I've followed tutorials by Houssem Dellai on how to sign-up and login from Xamarin. However my issue is how do I display the current logged in user's profile information(Cell number, address etc) when they click on "My Profile" tab. In my database I have 2 tables, one is called AspNetUsers and the other is called Profile(this table has the additional user details that I want to display e.g Address, cell number, gender)

So far, I've created my Profile Model:

```
public class ProfileBindingModel
{
    
    public int Pro_Id { get; set; }

    public string Pro_IDNo { get; set; }

    public string Pro_Gender { get; set; }

    public string Pro_Province { get; set; }

    public string Pro_City { get; set; }

    public string Pro_Postal { get; set; }

    public string Pro_User { get; set; }
    
    public System.DateTime Pro_DoB { get; set; }

    public string Pro_CellNo { get; set; }
}
```

and I've created this class :

```
public class UserDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();
    private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    public bool _isbusy;
    //public ProfileBindingModel ProfileBindingModel { get; set; }
    public string Pro_IDNo { get; set; }

    public string Pro_Gender { get; set; }

    public string Pro_Province { get; set; }

    public string Pro_City { get; set; }

    public string Pro_Postal { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime Pro_DoB { get; set; }

    public string Pro_CellNo { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isbusy; }
        set
        {
            _isbusy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public async Task LoadUserDetails()
    {
        var username = Settings.Username;
        string accesstoken = Settings.AccessToken;
        if(username !=null)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("");
            var content = new StringContent("");

            var response = await _client.PostAsync("http://test.dev.co.za/api/Account/GetUsername?username=" + username + "", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseString);


            var userId = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("Id");
            if(userId != null)
            {
                var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
                var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accesstoken);
                var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://test.dev.co.za/api/Profile/CurrentUserProfile?userId=" + userId);
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProfileBindingModel>(json);

                UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails
                {


                    Pro_IDNo = result.Pro_IDNo,
                    Pro_CellNo = result.Pro_CellNo,
                    Pro_City = result.Pro_City,
                    Pro_DoB = result.Pro_DoB,
                    Pro_Gender = result.Pro_Gender,
                    Pro_Postal = result.Pro_Postal,
                    Pro_Province = result.Pro_Province,
                    IsBusy = false
                };
                

        }
            
        }
        else
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Oops","Couldn't Load Profile", "Ok");
        }
     }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This is my Xaml file:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:EasyJobsApp.ViewModel"
             x:Class="EasyJobsApp.Views.UserProfilePage"
             xmlns:fontawesome="clr-namespace:EasyJobsApp">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:UserDetails/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Logout" Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}" Clicked="Logout_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

  
    
    <StackLayout Padding="20">
        <Label Text="{Binding Pro_City}" TextColor="White"></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding Pro_CellNo}" TextColor="White"></Label>
        <Label Text="" TextColor="White"></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding Pro_Gender}" TextColor="White"></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding Pro_Province}" TextColor="White"></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding Pro_City}" TextColor="Black"></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding Pro_Postal}" TextColor="Black"></Label>
       

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>` and this is my Xaml.cs file: `

     private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
     ApiServices apiServices = new ApiServices();
    
     public UserProfilePage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();  
     }
     private async void Logout_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
     }`
```

Comment: Please do not post code as images

Comment: Hi Jason, I removed the images and replaced them with the code

Comment: where are you calling `LoadUserDetails`?

Comment: I tried calling LoadUserDetails on the OnAppearing method but nothing wall displaying on my Xaml page

Comment: this `UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails` creates a new local instance of `UserDetails` instead of updating the properties on the current instance

Comment: You can declare a few strings and then set them with your user informations. Then set those strings label's text binding at xaml.

Comment: Do you check the code `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProfileBindingModel>(json);` to see if it really gets the data from the website?

Comment: I've updated my LoadUserDetails by removing UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails and on my Xaml.cs I added the OnAppearing method to call LoadUserDetails and the user info displays now

Comment: protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
base.OnAppearing();
await (BindingContext as UserDetails).LoadUserDetails()
CellNo.Text = (BindingContext as UserDetails).Pro_CellNo.ToString()
IDNo.Text = (BindingContext as UserDetails).Pro_IDNo.ToString()
DoB.Text = (BindingContext as UserDetails).Pro_DoB.ToString()
Gender.Text = (BindingContext as UserDetails).Pro_Gender.ToString()
Province.Text = (BindingContext as UserDetails).Pro_Province.ToString()
City.Text = (BindingContext as UserDetails).Pro_City.ToString()
Postal.Text = (BindingContext as UserDetails).Pro_Postal.ToString()
}

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT yes, I checked the code and it was pulling the data. My issue was how do I display the data but thanks to Jason and Mert I am able to display the data